# findChessboardCorners does not work in opencv 4.5.2 python

Tags: camera-calibration, opencv, python

I am using findChessboardCorners() in python to find corners, but it never worked. I tried grey images and black and white images, but it still does not work. Can someone help me? Here are the code and images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def draw_img(img):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
    
img = cv2.imread("a.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Gray
complement_gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)  # Complement gray
_, bw_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # black and white

success = False
for i in range(3,12):
    for j in range(3,12):
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, (i,j), cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS)
        if ret:
            success = True;
            break;
            
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(complement_gray, (i,j), cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS)
        if ret:
            success = True;
            break;
            
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(bw_img, (i,j), cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS)
        if ret:
            success = True;
            break;
            
if success:
    print("Success")
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your images seem ultra hazy, have you tried this on a flat chessboard image? You can build some clear test images and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The hazy problem is caused by the incorrect focus. The distance between camera and object is short and caused out-focus. It can't be fixed.

Comment: In that case your question is incorrect in my opinion. To me this does not seem to be opencv's problem. Solution to focusing distance problem that I can propose is to build a larger checkerboard pattern. Not that it's of interest to you but I did my master's thesis using something like this long back https://scholarcommons.usf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2173&context=etd . Page 23. Good luck!